# Responsive design - DOM elements limit and HTML vs SVG performance

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design

I created yearly "heat map" where each day is `div` square consists of three other `div` elements.
Together it's giving me over thousand of DOM elements. And everything seams to be ok till I'm not trying to see this map on my tablet (HP Slate 10). When I open this on tablet it immediately crash.

(I removed JS and loaded only HTML and CSS but that not helped so I'm sure that is no JS issue)

Single day HTML:

```
<div class="addTooltip tileCell" data-day="10" data-month="8">
    <div class="tile">
        <div class="face side_a"></div> <!-- I'm using this to do animation -->
        <div class="face side_b"></div> <!-- I'm using this to do animation -->           
    </div>        
</div>
```

My questions:

- is there any reasonable number of elements which shouldn't be exceed?
- would it be faster if I'll create the same map using SVG?

EDIT: The answer to my question is yes - the SVG performs much better in described situation.

Comment: you should profile the performance of your page and check for the bottlenecks on your tablet (e.g. RAM usage). The more your page is complex in terms of DOM structure, the higher the resource consumption: see https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is too many DOM elements, and you don't have any preventive interactivity requirements, `canvas` would be the best option, as adding "elements" to a canvas drawing does not add to the DOM.